# How to upload magento website to my godaddy windows hosting?

Tags: magento, localhost, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, web-hosting

I have created a magento store on my laptop on localhost now i want to host this store on my godaddy hosting(Windows) how can i do this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

### moving files and database

I assume these two steps are obvious:

1. copy all of your local files to production server
2. dump your magento local db and import it into your production server db

### editing in production server

now on your production server you need to follow these two steps:

1. edit app/etc/local.xml file and change database info
2. in production db,in its `core_config_data` table, you should find every records containing the url of your local installation, then you need to update those values;which can be found with this query:

```
     SELECT *
     FROM `core_config_data`
     WHERE `value` LIKE 'http://%';
```

edit (thanks to comments):
3. Do not forget to delete  `var` folder contents